Merging 2 sql queries into 1
I am extracting some database data using PostgreSQL via Grafana.
The first SQL gives me a list of user_ids (User2, User3...) who have interacted with a specific User1 I know beforehand:
SELECT DISTINCT user_id AS user
FROM transactions
WHERE (type_id, operation_id) IN (
    SELECT type_id, operation_id
    FROM transactions
    WHERE user_id = 11111 --This is User1
)
AND user_id != 11111;

The second SQL gives me some stats for ONE specific user_id (e.g. User2) from another table:
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT operation_id) AS "# of operations"
FROM
  operations
WHERE
  category = "category1" AND
  user_id = 22222 --This is User2

How can I "merge" both queries, so that, for each of the users retrieved from the 1st query (User2, User3... so I don't know them beforehand) I can get the stats on the second query (rather than only for a hardcoded User2)?
Thanks!

It would help if you showed some sample/mock input values and what result you're trying to get based on those. You can put those in a db<>fiddle.

JOIN the tables, merge the lists of conditions, then GROUP BY. You can also FILTER what goes into the aggregate functions, like the count(*) you used: demo at db<>fiddle
SELECT user_id 
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT o.operation_id)
         FILTER(WHERE category='category1')AS "# of category1 operations"
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT o.operation_id)
         FILTER(WHERE category='category2')AS "# of category2 operations"
FROM transactions AS t
JOIN operations AS o
USING (user_id)
WHERE (t.type_id, t.operation_id) IN (
    SELECT type_id, operation_id
    FROM transactions
    WHERE user_id = 11111 --This is User1
)
AND t.user_id <> 11111
AND category IN ('category1','category2')
GROUP BY user_id;




user_id
# of operations
# of category1 operations
# of category2 operations




22222
3
2
0


33333
1
1
0



Make sure those tables are indexed:
create index on transactions(type_id,operation_id); 
create index on transactions(user_id,type_id,operation_id);
create index on operations(user_id,category)include(operation_id); 

The demo test on 200k randomised rows in each table shows how these indexes help reduce the execution time from 200ms down to 5ms.

This is impressive, thank you so much @Zegarek! Follow-up question: What if I want to show 3 columns instead of 2: user_id, "#of operations for category1" and # of operations for category2" (where "category" is a property of the operations table)? Please keep in mind I edited my original 2nd query adding the line "category = "category1" AND"

@EuRomán You can use a FILTER clause for that. It really just filters what goes into the aggregate function it's attached to. I've added that to the answer and the demo. In other RDBMS you can sometimes see that emulated with a "conditional aggregate" like sum(case when category='category1' then 1 else 0 end) or count(case when category='category1' then 1 end).

Thanks a lot@Zegarek ! Somehow Grafana seems to not be able to handle so much data when using either FILTER or CASE inside COUNT... So I'll have to split the query into 2 (for category1 and category2) following your first version of your answer (before adding the FILTERs). In that case, would you just add a where condition at the end (before the GROUP BY line) like "AND category='category1'" or "AND category='category2'"? Or does the where have to be somewhere else inside the query? Thanks a lot again!

If you're only interested in counts of specific categories, you can add the condition that only pulls in those two, then instruct each count to only count one of those. You might also benefit from create index on transactions (type_id,operation_id); create index on operations (category); if you don't have those set up yet.

Thank you so much once again, @Zegarek. You've nailed it :) Best!
